# Change distance to text before and after newenvironment

Tags: environments, margins

I cannot find a way to specify a minimum distance between the environment and the preceding / following text.
Is there a way of setting a minimum for (A) and for (B) speciffically for my example environments?
They way it is now just looks too squashed to me.

[image]

The excerpt was produced using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{myexamplectr}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]

{\refstepcounter{myexamplectr} \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0.1mm, arc=0mm, #1] 
        \texttt{Example \themyexamplectr}: }{\end{tcolorbox}}
\numberwithin{myexamplectr}{chapter}

\newenvironment{example*}[1]
{%\refstepcounter{myexamplectr} 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm, arc=0mm]
         \texttt{#1}:
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\newtcolorbox{twocolBox}[1][]{
    sidebyside,
    enhanced,
    arc=0pt,
    boxsep=1mm,
    notitle,
    oversize,
    nobeforeafter,
    frame hidden,#1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space can be changed with `before skip=1cm,after skip=1cm`, see tcolorbox docu p. 82

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{myexamplectr}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
{\refstepcounter{myexamplectr} \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0.1mm, arc=0mm, #1] 
        \texttt{Example \themyexamplectr}: }{\end{tcolorbox}}


\newenvironment{example*}[1]
{%\refstepcounter{myexamplectr} 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm, arc=0mm]
         \texttt{#1}:
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\newtcolorbox{twocolBox}[1][]{
    sidebyside,
    enhanced,
    arc=0pt,
    boxsep=1mm,
    notitle,
    oversize,
    nobeforeafter,
    frame hidden,#1
}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}[before skip=1cm,after skip=1cm]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```